# In android how to pass parameters to an app with a custom URI

Tags: android, parameters, uri

I have an app that starts with a custom uri " E2L://" . In a EPUB I have a link "E2L://" that opens my app, but how can I pass parameters? and how can i get them from the app? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
public class Etiqueta extends Activity {
private CharSequence frase;
private EditText texto;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Uri data = getIntent().getData(); 
    if (data==null) { } else {
    String datos=data.toString();
    texto.setText(datos);
    }
}


}
```